# Как объединить в единую локальную сеть 2 роутера с разными провайдерами?

Tags: сеть

Добрый день.

Описание: в одно помещение заведено 2 кабеля с интернетом от разных провайдеров. Есть 2 роутера TP-Link Archer C20, в каждый подключен свой кабель соответственно. К каждому роутеру подключено N устройств (по LAN и по Wi-Fi).

Суть: как объединить эти 2 роутера и все устройства подключенные к ним в единую локальную сеть? Возможность соединить роутеры с помощью кабеля имеется.

P.S. В данной теме толком не разбираюсь, поэтому прошу помощи. Если для решения задачи необходимы какие-либо нюансы, пишите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А причем тут локальная сеть и провайдеры?

Comment: Ну сейчас устройства подключенные к роутеру 1 и устройства подключенные к роутеру 2 находятся в разных подсетях, у каждой подсети свой провайдер. Такую структуру необходимо оставить, но поверх все объединить в единую локальную сеть. Мой вопрос можно ли это реализовать и как?

Comment: Вам скорее всего, нужна схема `LAN-WAN`. Либо по `Wi-Fi`, через мост. Но если вы говорите в этом не понимаете, - это уже проблема.

Comment: Ну тут 2 пути: 1. Через протоколы динамической маршрутизации. 2. Через статическую маршрутизацию. Первый путь правильный, но я не могу найти в спецификациях арчера, что он поддерживает протоколы динамической маршрутизации. Тогда надо сделать так: на роутерах сделать разные сети 192.168.1.0/24 и 192.168.2.0/24 (как пример), соединить их проводом и прописать выдачу статичного dhcp либо, если возможно, статично адреса, далее необходимо статически прописать маршруты для этих сетей в сторону друг друга. Но я не уверен, что у Вас это получится сделать самостоятельно...

Comment: @PankrashinG.O."Проблема" вашего вопроса в том, что вам нужна пошаговая инструкция, как это настроить на ваших роутерах (например, какие кнопки нажимать в вебнюшечках этих роутеров). И написать ее сможет только тот, у кого такое (либо очень похожее) оборудование, и похожая ситуация с сетью. А всякие общие слова о маршрутизации, которые вам предложат, для вас будут бессмысленны. Самый лучший вариант в вашем случае - найти в вашей округе сетевика, который вам это настроит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Как это делается в теории

Существуют 2 варианта - через динамичную и статичную маршрутизацию. Я никогда не использовал TP-Link Archer и не могу найти у него в спецификациях что-то о динамической маршрутизации, так что придётся рассмотреть второй вариант, хотя предпочтителен первый.

Для организации L3-связности между двумя сегментами сети (двумя роутерами) понадобится 2 диапазона внутренних (до NAT) адресов на этих роутерах (например 192.168.1.0/24 и 192.168.2.0/24). Соединяем эти два роутера витой парой, прописываем на каждом статичную dhcp запись для роутера-соседа. Так, на первом роутере (192.168.1.1) второй должен получать адрес 192.168.1.2 и на втором роутере (192.168.2.1) первый должен получать 192.168.2.2 . Далее, на каждом роутере в сторону своего соседа надо прописать статический маршрут (в случае, если связности из сетей не появилось). Таким образом, на первом роутере из сети 192.168.1.0/24 необходимо прописать маршрут до 192.168.2.0/24 в сторону 192.168.2.1 через 192.168.2.2 и соответственно на втором роутере из сети 192.168.2.0/24 необходимо прописать маршрут в сторону 192.168.1.1 через 192.168.1.2 до сети 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ!